# ASP.Net Controls Don't Work if I used link to get to the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I Just noticed this odd bug. I have a Webpage with 2 drop down-lists, one of them will populate with data depending on what item the first one has selected.

I noticed if I get to the page by using the hyperlink I have in my website's menu, the controls will not update when an item is changed, but if I get to the page any other way everything works perfectly.

I have been looking for a solution but I have not been able to find a way to fix the problem.

I am using autopostback to update the page when selected index changes.

Seems to work for a while after I refresh, but a new session it will stop working even though it has nothing to do with a session.

Comment: It's real hard for us to figure out the problem if you don't post relevant code. You should probably include the functions that load and change the selection.

Comment: Probably your drop down is based in session data and you are losing your session. Like in a response redirect. But @mason is correct. We need to see code.

Comment: This is clearly an initiation issue but without the code is impossible to diagnose the issue

Comment: I'd agree about an init issue.  One could assume that the links in the drop down menu are on the same page and therefore a postback is occuring when using the menu, otherwise your page is being loaded and setup differs in each case.

Comment: the link to get to the page the contains the drop-down menu is just a simple hyper link on another page.